# Why does my Firebase query return the wrong order?

Tags: firebase

**BACKGROUND**

Hello guys, I am performing a query in Firebase that retrieves a list of messages:

```js
ref.child("messages").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

The above query works fine. It displays the messages in order.

A message contains the following properties/fields:

```
<message-id>: { 
    user-id: <user-id>,
    message: "This is a sample message",
    time: 1446534920014
}
```

**PROBLEM**

When displaying a message, I also need to display the user's name. So I need to add another query that retrieves the user's name using the `user-id` field:

```js
ref.child("messages").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    var message = snapshot.val();
            
    // get the user's name
    ref.child("users").child(message["user-id"]).once("value", function(userSnapshot) {
        // logs the results in the wrong order
        console.log(message, userSnapshot.val().name);
    }
});
```

The problem was the inner query returns the list of messages in the wrong order. Why? And what should be the correct way in order to display the messages in the correct order?

**EDIT**

Ok here you go. Below is the exported JSON:

```json
{
  "messages" : {
    "-K2FyInlsZqLdHou1QnA" : {
      "message" : "Message 1",
      "user-id" : "-K2Fxr1gdxynukjDzcIq"
    },
    "-K2FyOlw13MU9KHB5NQh" : {
      "message" : "Message 2",
      "user-id" : "-K2Fxr1gdxynukjDzcIq"
    },
    "-K2Fz2GxPgqGf8uDfK0d" : {
      "message" : "Message 3",
      "user-id" : "-K2Fy3uyw-RNcePo_Pn-"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "-K2Fxr1gdxynukjDzcIq" : {
      "name" : "John Joe"
    },
    "-K2Fy3uyw-RNcePo_Pn-" : {
      "name" : "Alfred"
    }
  }
}
```

My goal is just to display the messages (in order) along with the user's name. If I do this:

```js
ref.child("messages").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

It displays the messages in order, i.e. Message 1, Message 2, Message 3. But I still don't have the user's name so I need to look into the users list to retrieve the user's name before displaying the message:

```js
ref.child("messages").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    ref.child("users").child(snapshot.val()["user-id"]).once("value", function(userSnapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val(), userSnapshot.val().name);
    });
});
```

That returns a list of the messages including the user's name, but the problem is it's in the wrong order: Message 2, Message 1, Message 3

Comment: "the wrong order" is highly subjective and unfixable until you show us a sample of your data and the order you expect things to be in. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: That second callback is called whenever the user snapshot is downloaded.  One might be finished downloading before one that started earlier. You can't control the order of that asynchronous callback.

Comment: @AnidMonsur ok so what would be the correct way of retrieving the user's name based on the user's id?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I included a screenshot of the message list.

Comment: You are retrieving it the correct way. The issue is your callback structure. What's your goal? Surely you want to do more than console.log. We need to see more to provide a good answer.

Comment: A screenshot may be worth a 1000 words, but a screenshot of text is usually a poor substitute. You can export the JSON from Firebase easily and include it in the question in a textual format. That allows someone to copy/paste it into their answer or use it to test what you are having trouble with. See also [providing an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I updated my question to include the JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The messages are retrieved in the order you'd expect. You can easily verify this by adding some additional logging:

```
ref.child("messages").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    var message = snapshot.val();
    console.log(message.message);

    ref.child("users").child(message["user-id"]).once("value", function(userSnapshot) {
        console.log(message.message+': '+userSnapshot.val().name);
    });
});
```

The output from this on my recent runs has been:

```
"Message 1"
"Message 2"
"Message 3"
"Message 2: John Joe"
"Message 1: John Joe"
"Message 3: Alfred"
```

What you see here in the first three lines is that the messages are in order. But you then start retrieving the user for each of the messages; and those users don't necessarily come back in the order you fired/expected them.

This a very common problem when using AJAX on the web: as soon as network traffic is involved, the order of your code is not necessarily the order in which things happen.

The solution is always the same: don't depend on your code executing in a specific order. For example: you most likely want to display the message in a list in the DOM somewhere.

```
var ul = document.getElementById('messages');
ref.child("messages").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    var message = snapshot.val();
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.id = 'msg_'+snapshot.key();
    li.innerText = message.message;
    ul.appendChild(li);

    ref.child("users").child(message["user-id"]).once("value", function(userSnapshot) {
        li.innerText = userSnapshot.val().name + ': '+ li.innerText;
    });
});
```

Side note: you might want to consider adding a cache of user names. You'll now be calling out to the database for each message, for each user. This is an O(n^2) operation, so does not scale very well with the number of users.

Repro: http://jsbin.com/zofasi/edit?js,console

Comment: How could I do that for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60105179/data-loaded-onto-page-in-wrong-order-when-fetching-within-foreach-loop