# Posted messages on Firebase aren't displayed in chronological order

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

I'm working on making chat app with Firebase.
But, I’m having trouble implementing this chat system.

**Issue:**
  If you reload the browser, posted messages on Firebase aren't displayed in chronological order.

**Structuring Data:**

```
{
    "users": { // User List
        "user001": { // UserId
            "name": "TestUser001", // UserName
            "image": "https://foobar.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/avator01.png" // ImageUrl
        },
        "user002": { // UserId
            "name": "TestUser002", // UserName
            "image": "https://foobar.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/avator02.png" // ImageUrl
        }
    },
    "rooms": { // Room List
        "room001": "RoomA", //RoomID and RoomName
        "room002": "RoomB"
    },
    "messages": { // Message List
        "room001": {  // Message each room
            "message0001": { // Message
                "user": "user001", // UserId
                "message": "Hello!", // body
                "created_at": 1447402838902 // timestamp
            }
        },
        "room002": {  // Message each room
            "message0002": { // Message
                "user": "user002", // UserId
                "message": "Hi!", // body
                "created_at": 1447402844583 // timestamp
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Source code:**

```
// Message List
var messages = dataStore.child('/messages/' + currentRoomId);
var user;

messages.orderByChild("created_at").on('child_added', function(dataSnapshot) {
  var data = dataSnapshot.val();

  dataStore.child('/users/' + data.user).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var date = new Date(data.created_at);
    var timestamp = date.toLocaleString();
    user = snapshot.val();

    $('<div/>').html( data.message ).prependTo('#messages');
    $('<div/>').html( '<a href="../' + user.name + '" target="_blank" >' + user.name + ' </a>' + ' ' + '<small>' + timestamp + '</small>' ).prependTo('#messages');
    $('<div/>').html( '<img src=' + user.image + ' class="image" />' ).prependTo('#messages');
  });
});
```

**Screen image:**
[image]

Comment: The `/messages/ outer loop loads in the correct order, but the loading of the users can happen in any order. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497409/why-does-my-firebase-query-return-the-wrong-order/33525809#33525809

Comment: Hi Frank.
My chat system ran correctly when I fixed it as you taught me.
I appreciate your kindness.